# How to Display SharePoint o365 list items on a html web site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to Display Sharepoint list items on a non sharepoint site? Consider I have asp.net website called www.abc.com, so i need to display some announcements from my sharepoint o365 online site on abc.com . Please note that my sharepoint online has multi factor authenication as well.(username+password+pingID). so please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET web application, we can using CSOM(C#) code to get list items from SharePoint Online. The following code for your reference.

```
var site = @"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";               
var login = "lz@xx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "Password";
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(site))  
{  
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();  

    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())  
    {  
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);  
    }    
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);  
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");  
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);  
    context.Load(items);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    var listData=items; 
}
```

We can also use REST API with C# code to get list data, then show the data in a gridview in asp.net application page.

Reference: [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#sharepoint-list-item-tasks)

Comment: thanks. mine is html website.  i just want to display my share point online list items on of my <div> on my html site. Real requirement is to from html site in textbox if we put keyword like "where is data" it should display 5 results from sharepoint in one <div>. is that possible?

Comment: If you want to show data in html page, you need create a web service and get data from web service using jQuery ajax.

Comment: Can you please provide any userful articles regarding same ? it will help me a lot. also note that our share point has multi factor authentication username password and next pingID after that only we can login. SO i am looking around work around to resolve this .

Comment: actually i am trying this article : http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/  .... but not able to login to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf